# What do you get when you reheat and cool clotted cream?

Tags: clotted-cream

I made clotted cream and tried to heat it for serving. It immediately disintegrated so I tried to salvage it by freezing it. It solidified into something yellowish and left some liquid at the bottom, just like when I made the clotted cream. Is the solid part still clotted cream or is it something else?

Comment: What recipe did you follow for making it? I found version based on heavy cream, normal cream, and creme double. Yellowish would make me speculate about butter, but that is pure speculation on my side.

Comment: Why would you heat clotted cream? It's used in the same way as whipped cream or ice cream...

Comment: @Layna: Low heated fatty, heavy cream for 12 hours then refrigerated overnight.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: Because I store it in the fridge and I don't want to eat it cold.

Comment: It's meant to be eaten cold, or at least room temperature. It's definitely not meant to be eaten warm. If you don't want to eat it stone cold, take the amount you plan on using out of the fridge a couple of hours before you want to eat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description and re-reading the instructions for your version: yes, what you had on top was still clotted cream.

They liquid on the bottom should be whey, which gets separated from the rest during the clotting-process. Re-heating did start the same process you used originally, and left-over whey separated again.

Answer (score -1):

You made butter. Unsalted butter, but butter nonetheless